# CQL: Unable to Null Check in "Where" Clause

Tags: cassandra, cql

Try to return all rows where a specific field is null or not null.

```
select * from ADDRESS where addr1 = null;
```

or

```
select * from ADDRESS where addr1 = 'NULL';
```

addr1 can be a boolean or text field.

I've tried `!= null`, `is null`, `<> null`, and `isnull(addr1, 'NULL')`

but I get

```
no viable alternative at input '='
```

or

```
no index columns present in by-columns clause with "equals' operator"
```

Using Cassandra 1.1.1 & Java 1.7_05

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CQL doesn't have the concept of NULL (yet- see [CASSANDRA-3783](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3783)). The right thing to do instead depends on your particular situation.

Comment: so if I upgrade to Cassandra 1.2 and CQL 3.0, will this solve my issue?

Comment: Can't say for sure. Cassandra 1.2 doesn't exist yet, so there are no guarantees about what tickets will be implemented for it. At any rate, it shouldn't be *necessary* to upgrade to 1.2 to solve your problem.

Comment: sorry, i ment Cassandra 1.1.2. They are on 1.1.3 as I look today. I will update Cassandra and try it.

Comment: Upgrading to 1.1.2 or 1.1.3 definitely will not solve your problem. You need to change your queries.

Comment: thanks paul, i just want to check if data was inserted by the app by checking for nulls. if you can point me to the syntax, it would be helpful. i already did searches here and on google... =(

Comment: Like I said, there is no syntax for that yet; CQL doesn't have the concept of NULL. Whatever problem you're trying to solve is probably still solvable without using NULL, but I can't tell you exactly how without knowing what the situation is. You should probably ask a new toplevel question and state what you're trying to do (instead of how you're trying to do it).

Comment: It works now, CASSANDRA-3783 was resolved and newer Cassandra releases accept `addr1 = null` .

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use cqlsh to select the required columns - normally the primary key and the column of interest using -e option and use grep for identifying null entries. Set "paging off" also in the query to get all the results otherwise by default only 100 rows will be returned.

cqlsh <ip> -u <user name> -p <password> -e "paging off;select * from ADDRESS where addr1 = null;" | grep null