# Replace Null function in Cassandra Select Query

Tags: java, cassandra

A set of records are to be selected from a cassandra table.

```
select a1,a2,a3 from tableB where solr_query='...';
```

Where some of a1 (`int` type) are null.

1. In Oracle, we could use `nvl(a1,0)`.
2. In MS SQL Server, we could use `isnull(a1,0)`.

*I don't know the same to handle in cassandra way*.

### **How I handle this in Java :**

Create `TableBObject` class , in which all attributes are mapped with `tableB` (cassandra table).

Create Java accessor interface with the accessor method

```
@Accessor
public interface TableBAccessor
{
    @Query(select a1,a2,a3 from tableB where solr_query='...';)
    Result<TableBObject> getTableOnSolrQuery (@Param("solrQuery") String solrQuery);

}
```

In my calling method, I have created the `mappingManager` and used :

```
TableBAccessor tableBAccessor = mappingManager.createAccessor();

    List<TableBObject> tabBList = tableBAccessor.getTableOnSolrQuery("someSolrQuery").all();

    for(TableBObject tabB : tabBList){

    int a1 = tabB.getA1(); /*a1 column in cassandra table*/

    if(a1!=null){
    // replace a1 by some int value (zero / something else)

    }
  }
```

Above way, I am handling the same in Java.

It is consuming additional effort to me.

What's the solution in `cassandra` other than handling the same in `Java` Code ?

### **Can I not write like : **

`select isnull(a1,0),a2,a3 from tableB where solr_query='...';` or

`select nvl(a1,0),a2,a3 from tableB where solr_query='...';`

??

### **My Question Is : **

If **Yes**, then ***how*** ? If **not**, then ***why*** ?

Comment: Hi Surajit, Consider reading cassandra's documentation maybe.

Comment: Nope, I didn't find anything useful there :(

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in support for functions like `nvl` in Cassandra.

In theory, since Cassandra 2.2 you could define an [UDF](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL-2.2.html#udfs) (user-defined function) that does what you are looking for; however, currently it is not possible to call functions passing literals as arguments, so `nvl(a1,0)` would throw an error; this limitation will go away with [CASSANDRA-10783](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10783).

In the meanwhile, you should either avoid storing nulls in the first place, or apply the function client-side.

Answer (score 1):

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32605319/select-rows-where-a-column-is-null-in-cassandra) that Cassandra doesn't support querying based on null, even for secondary indexes.

You may need to adapt the given solution to your case: have another boolean column called `a1_uninitialized` defaulted to `true`, that will help you handle the empty values.